# Using display:none hides all elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django

I'm using jQuery to display 10 elements at a time. Here is my code

```
var max_items_page = 10;

    $('#song_list div:lt('+max_items_page+')').show();
    var shown = null;
    var items = $("#song_list").find('div').length;

    $('#loadMore').on('click',function(e){
        shown = $('#song_list div:visible').length+max_items_page;
        if(shown<items) {
            $('#song_list div:lt('+shown+')').show();
        }
        else {
                $('#song_list div:lt('+items+')').show();
                $('#loadMore').hide();
        }
    });
```

This is the code to display the song list

```
<div id='song_list'>
    {% for song in dj_song_list %}
    <div>
        <p class="song"><h3>#{{ forloop.counter}} {{ song.name }}</h3></p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<button id='loadMore'>Load more</button>
```

Here is the css

```
#song_list div {
    display:none;
}
```

This displays no results and just the Load more button. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Display:none hides all, so you're hiding all of the items in #song_list.

Comment: If I don't use that I get all the results.

Comment: ...but you are choosing to hide everything...

Comment: Here is an example of how it is working here http://jsfiddle.net/gebm4/

Comment: the javascript and css look Okay. Check in the inspector or source view that you actually have divs in your song_list.

Comment: The divs appear in the source code.

Comment: @Doorhandle, I think it was quite clear by looking at his code that `display:none` was hiding all items but jQuery was making them visible again.

Comment: The jquery file being linked had a spelling mistake in the file name. My bad. It's working now. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You should delete the question if there's no point to it.

Comment: This question has answers and so cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

In your code you're hiding all of div tag in #song_list. So if you want to hide except the first one, just do this:

```
#song_list div:not(div:first-child) {
    display:none;
}
```

Or you can show what you want with jquery:

```
#song_list div {
        display:none;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$('#song_list div').slice(1,10).show();
```

Comment: Could be wrong but I think OP wants 10 at a time, not 1. I also think that he has set `display:none` to all DIV's so that jQuery can `show()` them.

Comment: Ok. I don't know OP update his question. Now I have just edited my answer

Answer (score -2):

The issue is not about the css, your display:none to hide all first is reasonable.

can you make sure that

```
 $('#song_list div:lt('+max_items_page+')').show();
```

runs correctly? I mean that piece of code do run after the divs are rendered.

Comment: This isn't an answer to his question.